# QProcess и ssh получить вывод

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ssh

Можно ли через QProcess получить вывод как в консоли?
Запустить процесс типа ("ssh", param) и получить с него ответ на запрос.

Comment: не вижу, причин, почему это кто-нибудь мог бы запретить...

Comment: ...подразумевая конечно, что настроена авторизация по ключу или какой-то альтернативное средство для запроса пароля (`ssh-askpass`) — голый ssh будет слушать пароль только напрямую с tty'я...

Comment: Да вы правы, про авторизацию забыл упомянуть, она тоже мне понадобится. Было бы неплохо получить пример)

Comment: попозже сделаю, если не забуду... сейчас лень...